# iFrame onclick button open in new tab with results

Tags: javascript, html

I have an iFrame tag on one of my tabs that when clicked on 'Compare now', it shows results from an insurance agency.

```
<iframe src="https://www.compulife.net/website/1295/quoter.html" width="750 pixels" id="test" name="test" height="750 pixels" frameborder="0" formtarget="_blank"></iframe>
```

Would it be possible to target the button class even tho it's in a iFrame to open in a new browser tab once the 'Compare Now' button is clicked? Below, is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: If the site embedded in an iframe does not belong to you and you cannot modify it’s code, or if it’s not on the same domain as the parent site, there’s nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

In the Iframe tag, there is a property called formtarget="_blank", remove it and it should solve the issue

Comment: Unfortunately, that still displays the results on the same tab even after removing that piece.

Comment: @SemirSmajlović did you tried using window.open on the click of button, open it by window.open("foo.html", "_blank"); check if it's working

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta, how can I include that in the iFrame code?

Comment: You can use the script tag in the iframe window.

Answer (score 0):

Can you ask compulife.net to add target="_blank" inside the form on the page quoter.html, when you call, for example "quoter.html?xyz"

All other solutions are not reliable and not legal without their approval (including creating a copy of the page on your web and modifying the form there).